# See battery percentage on the panel in Plasma 5.8

Tags: kde, battery, plasma5

It seems Plasma 5.8 cannot display battery percentage in the panel, as explained [here](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=225&t=141577&p=394421#p380767).

I have found a solution and I am posting this in order to provide an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As tested in Linux Mint 18.3 KDE:

The battery displayed in the Plasma 5.8 panel is part of the widget **System Tray**.

A separate widget is available called **Battery Time** which can add this option.

Click the Panel settings button, *Add widgets > Get new widgets > Download new plasma widgets*: there, search "battery", and install the one called Battery Time.

It can also be found at https://store.kde.org/p/1166501.

After that, go again to Panel settings, *Add widgets*, search and add *Battery Time*. By default it displays both percentage and time remaining, this can be changed in its settings.

[image]

To avoid seeing two batteries in the panel, hide the one in the system tray: click the panel settings button, put the mouse over the system tray, check the settings button there: either disable Battery and Brightness under General tab, or just hide it under Entries tab.

[image]

If one prefers to still see the system tray battery icon (which has the advantage of displaying more info, like the charging sign, and of providing more tools, like brightness level) **and** have a percentage level beside that, this setting can be used: go to *System tray* settings and disable *Battery and Brightness* under *General* tab; add  a **second** System tray widget to the panel, and in its settings disable/hide all items except *Battery and Brightness*:

[image]

Then, disable the battery icon in the Battery Time widget settings and move the second tray and the Battery Time widgets close to each other.

[image]